# How to add storage account to existing virtual machine in azure

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, storage

I created a virtual machine with a storage account. I used to configure developer things but by mistake I star production things there.

Well, someone from my team dropped all "developer" thing.

Now, I'm trying to see how I can assign a new storage account but, I don't see any option except for "create virtual disk", and for personal reasons I prefer storage account, does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think I (and presumably no one else) understand your question. Do you want to present the "storage" directly to your VM? You can use Azure File Share, which will work as a network shared folder or local disks. These are the only options you have for a VM.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about mate.

Comment: Jason Ye - MSFT understand it :) sorry, my english is poor, :'( but almost somebody could answer my doubt

Answer (score 1):

> how I can assign a new storage account

Do you mean your team will delete storage account which contain your production data? And you want to assign a new storage account to keep your OS disk and data disk?

If your VM's OS disk and data disk all in that storage account, to keep your data, we should create new storage account, and **copy** os VHD and data disk to that storage account, then use this OS VHD to **create a new VM**, then attach data disk to this new VM.

If just data disk on that storage account, we can create a new storage account and attach new data disk to that VM, and copy data to the new disk.

About copy data from this storage account to another storage account, we can use [Azcopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) to copy it.

Comment: @sGermosen Please let me know if you need more help:)